# How to get coupan code(Promotion code) amount for an order (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, sales-order, coupon, coupon-codes

I am getting the coupon code(promotional code) for an order 
For a coupon code, I am using this

```
$order->getCouponCode();
```

How to get the coupon code `discounted price` so I can show it to the user.
Like `gift card` I am getting gift card amount

For gift card name - `$orderInfo->getGiftCards()`

For gift amount - `$orderInfo->getGiftCardsAmount()`

I am showing all the information like this

[image]

I need to show coupon code option, I am not able to get the coupon code discounted price.

How to get coupon code price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$order->getDiscountAmount();` or `$order->getDiscount();`